# How would I find the intersection of multiple data sets?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I'm reading a study about a certain drug and how it might cause some kidney issues as a longterm side effect. To be more precise the study is about PPIs (proton pump inhibitors).

I don't know why but the guys working on it did not present the intersection (which is really important I believe) of data sets.

Here is the picture:

[image]

I know that this is quite impossible what I would like, but is there at least some kind of approximation formula on how I could get:

**How many people have diabetes and chronic lung disease**

or as another example:

**diabetes and lung disease and hyperlipidemia.**

Unfortunately no other relevant parameters are present.

**N** is the number of people in the study, the number in the parenthesis is the percentage based on the big N for every disease separately calculated .

**Explaining intersection:**
By intersection I mean, for example, How would I get the number of people based on this data set who have diabetes, chronic lung disease and peripheral artery disease OR maybe: Dementia and Hep C. etc. Something like a VENN diagram intersection circle between two or multiple data sets

Here is the whole picture, Is it possible to make the intersection out of this data on the image?
[image]

Here is the entire study in PDF 12 pages. https://www.filedog.io/StarTurtle

Comment: What is "intersection"?

Comment: You are showing marginal descriptive statistics, namely, frequency of positive value, for each of 9 binary variables. Of course it would be possible to obtain frequencies for any combination among the variables - if you have the original dataset. Do you have it? Alternatively, you could estimate the co-occurence frequencies from the literature or official health care documents, if you dig and find enough info.

Comment: Read the explanation above, I've edited my question

Comment: @ttnphns I've uploaded the entire data sheet, Could I get the intersection from all the given data that I've uploaded?

Comment: I agree with ttnphns. There are multiple intersections possible given these data. So the answer is 'no', since there is no unique intersection that produces the given frequencies, you can not determine *the* intersection (Imagine your venn diagram analogy, as a graphical intuitive explanation, with this data you only know the circle sizes, but you have a freedom to shift them and give different degree of overlap, so you cant know intersections). Regarding solutions: the number of participants is very big. It could be that this is a research database to which you can get access to the raw data.

Comment: eugen, It is quite simple to compute frequency for any combination of conditions if you have the _data_, i.e. individuals by features dataset. Do you have _that_?

Comment: @ttnphns I'll show you what've got, I'll upload the entire PDF document. so you could at least tell me how would I solve my issue or what approach could I take at least.

Comment: Also, it is unclear whether you want to compute frequencies (of combinations of conditions) or you want to _plot_ them as a picture. In the second case your question is mostly about data visualization.

Comment: I've uploaded the link, check my edited question It would be nice if you could give an answer based on everything I've provided at least a guiding answer (I'll definitely award you with the bounty)

Comment: Why do you call it "multiple" data sets? Because these are comprised of not same individuals, or why?

Comment: In their research they used the algorithm of Schneeweiss https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28237709 to select covariates. They speak of top 500 covariates plus demographic data, it is unclear whether they also did the subanalysis in which they use the interaction terms of the top 20 covariates plus demographic variables and a group of pre-selected covariates. So they may have used intersections like you suspect can be important. It is not so nice that they have not been very clear about the used covariates in the models. However imho it is not neccesary to publish these as descriptive data.

Comment: If you really like to know the intersections. Then you can go look into the used database yourself (or maybe just email/call the authors),

Comment: @MartijnWeterings tnx for the explanation. Maybe it is the best thing to contact the authors. The thing is that these drugs PPIs are on constant bombardment for the last 2 years (they suppress stomach acid) and news are reporting bad stuff about them but if you dig deep into the studies you can find many flaws and when you analyze the data carefully  you can see that there isn't too much to be worried about this is why I'm interested so much in that.

Comment: "when you analyze the data carefully you can see that there isn't too much to be worried" do you mean that their analysis is biased/wrong (for instance: the hazard ratio should be closer to 1 if you analyze it with better adjustment for confounding) or do you mean that the results of their analysis is not that much to worry about (for instance: a hazard ratio of 1.19 is not much to worry about)?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I'm saying  that 19% of increased risk HZ=1.19 is nothing to worry about considering factors like median age, diseases which those patients have (the population from which the data was evaluated) medication they take along with PPIs etc. etc. If this was a study done on people with a median age of less than 40 years who are in good health and not having so much medical condition this study would probably become useless..

Comment: Anyways It would be nice if anyone could give decent answer rather than extending the comment section.

Comment: eugen, my personal recommendation would be to get the raw data from the authors, otherwise it is difficult to accomplish what you want. Meanwile, you may just delete your question (I doubt it can be answered positively/helpfully).

Comment: I'll definitely keep it, because of the useful comments.

Comment: You could change the question (which has a simple negative answer, and might be why not so many people care to post the answer, and first you get lots of comments that investigate the question). Based on your comments it seems you want to show something else/more than just getting the value of the intersection. The intersection actually seems irrelevant for your goal if you just want to point out that the effect is not something to worry (much) about.

Comment: "If this was a study done on people with a median age of less than 40 years who are in good health", surely there may be less problems with the kidney issues in total, however in terms of hazard rate, this might very well go up, because there is also less background of the kidney problems in the control group.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Ofcourse, totaly agree with you on that but I just want to say based on some other information that I've gathered and investigated that this would not be the case (lower aged population). Of course that the intersection is not my endpoint, I wanna go deeper but I need that. It's a big puzzle missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I know this information is contained in the comments above, but a concrete answer can't hurt.*

The answer is ***no***, because there are multiple solutions which result in the same total disease counts.

Imagine that we represent each individual in the study with a $1$-by-$p$ vector $x$ (where $p$ is the number of diseases). Each element of $x$ is then $0$ or $1$, where $0$ indicates the absence of the disease and $1$ indicates its presence. Then we have $n$ of these $1$-by-$p$ vectors, and we build an $n$-by-$p$ array $X$ by appending them sequentially row-wise. The sums of each column must add up to the total number of instances of each of the $p$ diseases, but that is the only constraint we have, and it is satisfied for a great many unique instances of $X$. Since there are obviously multiple solutions satisfying the only constraint provided, there is no way to achieve your goal with only the information provided.

Edit: My answer is a slight oversimplification of this problem because the individuals don't have specific identities, i.e., rearranging the rows of $X$ is not a different instance of $X$ for this application, so it's not quite as simple as saying that we only have $p$ equations (disease instance sums) and $np$ variables (elements of $X$). It still isn't possible to find these "intersections," though.